# Modify list with loop in Python: Is my method of doing so wrong?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have just started learning Python so i just wanted to get something straight.
I want to make a function that repeatedly appends the sum of the current last three elements of the list "lst" to "lst", x number of "times".
As far as i understand you should not change a list while iterating over it, so my second solution is wrong, right? Even though it produces the same result as the first function?

```
def appendsums(lst, times):
    count = 0
    for i in range(times):
        if count <= times:
            sums = sum(lst[-3:])
            lst.append(sums)
            count += 1
    return lst
```

Here is my second solution

```
def appendsums(lst, times):
    count = 0
    while count <= times:
        sums = sum(lst[-3:])
        lst.append(sums)
        count += 1
    return lst
```

Regards

Comment: You're not iterating over the list in either version, so I don't see what the problem's supposed to be.

Comment: In first solution you don't need `count` or any checking e.g. `count <= times`

Comment: The `count <= times` check is wrong in both versions; if you count from `0` to `times`, that's `times+1` values of `count` and `times+1` loop iterations. It should be `count < times` in the second version and removed entirely in the first, since the `for` loop makes `count` redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, you shouldn't iterate over a list while editing. But as pointed by other users, none of the above examples are iterating over the list `lst`.

Here is an example of iteration:

```
for item in lst:
    # Do something
```

If you need to iterate over a list while editing it, make a copy and iterate over the copy:

```
copy_lst = lst[:]
for item in copy_lst:
     # edit lst
```

I'd stick with the following code:

```
def appendsums(lst, times):
    for i in range(times):
        lst.append(sum(lst[-3:]))
    return lst
```

Comment: There is no need to slice the list, since we only append after the sum is complete.

Comment: The slice is because we only want the last 3 elements, not because we're worried about changing the list while iterating over it.

Comment: Oh, I missed that point in the question. Sorry, I'm fixing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its generally unsafe because iterators on the container aren't informed that a change has occurred. You usually want to create a temporary list and then modify the target list at the end.

Also, as a side note, I think you may want count to be less than times (and not equal to it).

In its current form, when I set times to 5, it adds six entries.

```
>>> def appendsums(lst, times):
...   count = 0
...   while count <= times:
...     sums = sum(lst[-3:])
...     lst.append(sums)
...     count += 1
...   return lst
... 
>>> appendsums([1,2,3], 5)
[1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 20, 37, 68, 125]
```